# What does the javascript library they used in fsharp documents

Tags: javascript, f#

When I visit some F# library documentation such [FsUnit](http://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/), they seems using some awesome javascript library that when I hover the mouse on some variable, a popup tips shows the type information about that variable. I would like to write a simple tutorials that is about F#. If I could add that script, I think the experience will be awesome. So does anyone knowns what the library is?

Answer (score 6):

Its [FSharp.Formatting](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting). The HTML formatting bit is http://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/codeformat.html